# Python open a file in a subdirectory - linux

Tags: python, linux, directory

Is it possible to open a file for reading in a sub directory without having to use os.listdir()? Something like this maybe?

```
f1 = open('/SCRIPT/PYTHON/monomer-b/{}'.format(xyzfile)).read()
```

I am running the python script in /SCRIPT/PYTHON  the files that I want to call is in /SCRIPT/PYTHON/monor-b. Any suggestions

Comment: have you tried anything? what is exactly your case?

Comment: Why can't you use `os.path.listdir`?

Comment: sure. os.listdir is one way to get file names but there are others. the open command doesn't care. it just wants the file name. As suggested, you really should just give it a try.

Comment: Why would you _need_ to use `os.listdir`?

Comment: I am getting No such file or directory found

Comment: try `print('/SCRIPT/PYTHON/monomer-b/{}'.format(xyzfile))` then go to the command line and see if the file is there.

Comment: Your code is looking for `monomer-b` but you say you're looking for `monor-b`.  Probably `monomer-b` is right, but it shows how easy it is to make a typo..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use relative paths while opening files in python:

```
import os  
file_content = open(os.path.join('./monomer-b', xyzfile)).read()
```

Also, by default all paths looks up starting at current directory, so the './' part of subdir name is not necessary. Using `os.path.join` is better practice than string concatenation or formatting, because it use correct path separators and another OS-specific things.